# How to do texture colors looking the same as in the jpg

Tags: texturing

I would like to create a texture based on an image that has the same color (in the viewport and in the render) as the jpg file. Independent from the light source. In 3ds max I used self illumination for that. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?
So if there is #000000 color in the jpg pixel, I should see #000000 in the render and in the viewport. If there is #123456 color in a jpg pixel, I should see #123456 in the render and in the viewport.

Similar to emission but that's not 100% is the same as the original...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting unexpected results because of the Color Management (in Render settings) - change the View Transform from **Filmic** to **Standard** if you want your render to match the input texture

[image: Color Management]

Emission shader is OK, you can also get the same result without adding any explicit shader, just connect the texture node to Surface of your Material Output.

[image: Using texture without a shader]